# Why does using Date.UTC() return a completely different month value compared to Date()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I've been working with Dates lately for a project and have noticed something strange that I don't think makes sense (or, at least it doesn't make sense to me).

In javascript, you can create a new date, and by default, if you get the month, it will return the current month number minus one.

```
let dt = new Date();//Assume 30/8/2018
dt.getMonth();// returns 7
```

You can also create a new date to run from UTC using an existing date, and because javascript's *.getMonth()* method for Dates always returns the month number minus one, you add one to get the correct month... However, *Date.UTC(...)* returns the next month and not the current/correct month

(Assume *dt* in the below snippet is the same as the above snippet with the current time)

```
let utc_dt = new Date(//Assume 30/8/2018
    Date.UTC(
        dt.getFullYear(),
        dt.getMonth()+1,
        dt.getDate(),
        dt.getHours(),
        dt.getMinutes(),
        dt.getSeconds()
    )
);
utc_dt.getMonth();// returns 9
```

Why does using *Date.UTC()* return a completely different month value compared to *Date()*?

I understand that UTC and the browsers time is not generally the same, but surely it wouldn't ever be out by a month?

Comment: because you have `dt.getMonth()+1`, month is zero based

Comment: "you add one to get the correct month" if you *get* a 0-11 month, what makes you think the constructor *takes* a 1-12?

Comment: dt.getMonth() returns a zero-based number (for August, it returns 7), so you add one to the result to display the correct month (which would be 8). However, utc_dt.getMonth(), seems to be doing something differently by not being zero-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the +1, `dt.getMonth()` returns the **local month** based on system settings, whereas Date.UTC will interpret the second parameter as the **UTC month**.

The UTC month differs for the period of the local timezone offset either side of midnight on the last/first day of the month. So if today is 31 August locally, then you add 1, you're asking for 31 September which rolls over to 1 October.

Again, timezone offsets mean this effect is extended over the period of the timezone offset, so appears to happen at illogical times.

Comment: Right! That makes sense actually.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/date-utc-javascript/):

> Parameters Used:
>
> […]
>
> - month: To specify an integer
>   between 0 and 11 representing the month.
>
> […]

This means, that you simply should pass a value between 0 and 11, where 0 represents January and 11 represents December:

```js
let dt = new Date(); //Assume 30/8/2018
console.info(dt.getMonth()); // returns 7

let utc_dt = new Date( //Assume 30/8/2018
  Date.UTC(
    dt.getFullYear(),
    dt.getMonth(),
    dt.getDate(),
    dt.getHours(),
    dt.getMinutes(),
    dt.getSeconds()
  )
);
console.info(utc_dt.getMonth()); // returns 7
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But why does adding a +1 to the Date.UTC dt.getMonth change the value by two?

Comment: @TheBalmyOne It doesn't! You might assume wrong values in your code. In this separate example, adding 1 to the month parameter results in 8, not 9.

Comment: Running getMonth on dt returns 7, thats correct, running the utc_dt getMonth like you have in your post returns 7, that's correct, but when doing 'dt.getMonth+1' when initing the utc_dt, then running getMonth, it returns 9 (see: https://i.gyazo.com/e5bafe87929dee9a42065f3a65c746e6.png)

Comment: I just did the same, and I get 8 as a result. (Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106)

Comment: Odd, i'm on the same chrome version (68.0.3440.106) and I get a different result...  Aight, cool.. I might just reinstall chrome and see what happens with that. +1 thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179077/discussion-between-the-balmy-one-and-barthy).